# Javascript multiple values on the same ID

Tags: php, javascript, sajax

I have a loop in php that echos out a `<input type="hidden" id="lol" value=$id />`

Every time the loops go through i get a new value in the hidden input field as you can understand.

Now, im trying to grab the value from each of these items and get grab it with Javascript and SAJAX.
The javascript im using now works, But! It only grabs the first value (because the ID is the same on each input)

Javscript:

```
function Showbooking() {
    id = document.getElementById('lol').value;
    x_showBookingForm(id, do_showBookingForm);
}
function do_showBookingForm(html) {
    openPopup(600, 550, html);
}
```

As you can see im opening a POPUP with javascript aswell and exports the value into that popup window.

So on every popup I get the same value (the value from the first input).

How Do I get around this problem?

Comment: The "id" attribute must be unique on the page if it exists at all. That is, you can't share "id" values.  You can use the "class" attribute if you want the effect of "categorizing" elements.

Comment: If you aren't incrementing the value in the loop, how is it ever going to be anything but the same? Did you mean to use an `$id[$i]` or some other such variable?

Comment: No im not using $id.$i . Im trying to get some help on how to solve this. that might be a solution but, isent there any other way?

Comment: @oBo you're trying to do something that's explicitly defined as resulting in undefined, unpredictable behavior. Things will work out much better if you do something else :-) If you use the "class" attribute, you can use `.getElementsByClassName()` (in modern browsers).

Comment: ... or do as mplungjan suggests and use the "name" attribute.

Comment: ...or use the 'class' attribute; with getElementsByClassName()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Change ID to name
2. Use document.getElementsByName and loop

```
var lols = document.getElementsByName("lol");
var vals=[];
for (var i=0, n=lols.length;i<n;i++) {
  vals.push(lols[i].value);
}
alert(vals.join(","));
```

Comment: Careful using `name` for grouping non-radio inputs. iirc, `name` is what's used to identify posted data. Of course if you don't care about getting that stuff back on the server-side it doesn't matter... but probably worth mentioning.

Comment: When i Use either name or Classname I get the value Undefined.

id = document.getElementsByClassName('lol').value;

Answer (score 2):

`getElementById` says *element* rather than *elements* because it returns only one item. `id` is supposed to be unique. You could do something to the effect of:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var values = [];
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
    if(inputs[i].type === "hidden"){
        values.push(inputs[i].value;
    }
}
```